# Weird packing in iov (writev)?

Tags: c, io, printf

I'm investigating `writev` and`readv` and when I'm displaying the memory contents, I'm getting strange data:

```c
struct iovec *iov = malloc(sizeof(struct iovec) * 3);
iov[0].iov_base = test_string1;
iov[0].iov_len  = strlen(test_string1);
printf("test1: IOV: &%#x, IOV: %#x, IOV_BASE: &%#x, IOV_BASE: %#x IOV_LEN: &%#x IOV_LEN: %#x\n",
&iov[0], iov[0], &iov[0].iov_base, iov[0].iov_base, &iov[0].iov_len, iov[0].iov_len);
```

I'm expecting that:

- `IOV&` puts the location of `IOV`
- `IOV` puts the value stored.
- `IOV_BASE&` should put the location of `IOV_BASE`
- `IOV_BASE` should put the location of `test_string1`
- `IOV_LEN&` should put the location of `IOV_LEN`
- `IOV_LEN` should put the length of `test_string1`

However, when running it, I get these results:

```
test1: IOV: &0x603010, IOV: 0x400d34, IOV_BASE: &0xe, IOV_BASE: 0x603010 IOV_LEN: &0x400d34 IOV_LEN: 0x603018
```

Now, when printing `iov[0]` in gdb, I get these values:

```
(gdb) print iov[0]
$1 = {
  iov_base = 0x400d34, 
  iov_len = 14
}
```

What is really weird is `iov_len`. According to gdb, the length of `test_string1` is 14 characters (which it is); however, the program says its length is 6303768 (in decimal). The program does spit out the correct value for length, but it is not in the right spot (`IOV_BASE`).

Any ideas on why this sort of thing is happening?

Comment: `-Wall` is your friend -- use it, look at the warnings it gives, and try to understand what they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has pretty much nothing to do with the `readv()` and `writev()` functions, and it only bears tangentially on the `struct iovec` type that they both use.

You must always ensure that the conversion specifications in the format string passed to `printf()` correctly match the types of the remaining arguments passed in the same call.  You have not done this.  The `%x` field descriptor requires the corresponding argument to be an unsigned integer type of an appropriate width (and the `#` flag does not alter this).  Your actual arguments are a `struct iovec *`, a `struct iovec`, a `void **`, a `void *`, a `size_t *`, and a `size_t`.  *None* of those is correct for the given field type, except that the last would be correct if `size_t` were the same width as `int` (it usually isn't).

According to the standard, "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined" (C2011, 7.21.6.1/9, 7.21.6.3/2).  That applies to your call.  It is not very useful to think too hard about or try to explain undefined behavior, because it is undefined.

I'm not sure I follow your expected behavior, especially with respect to `iov[0]`.  That's a `struct`.  There are no conversion specifiers for `struct`s, and any conversion you happen to get -- if the program does not simply crash -- is likely to be idiosynchratic of your particular C implementation and perhaps of your program specifically, and maybe even of the phase of the moon (refer back to "undefined behavior").

You could try this to print details about your `struct iovec`:

```
printf("test1: IOV &: %p, IOV_BASE &: %p, IOV_BASE: %p, IOV_LEN &: %p, IOV_LEN: %#zx\n",
        (void *) &iov[0], (void *) &iov[0].iov_base, iov[0].iov_base,
        (void *) &iov[0].iov_len, iov[0].iov_len);
```

The `%p` conversion specifier is for printing pointers (to `void`).  The `z` width-specifier in the last conversion specifier indicates that the argument is the width of a `size_t` (and that argument is, in fact, exactly a `size_t`).  You cannot print the `struct` itself, so I omitted it.  I inserted casts to convert pointer arguments to type `void *`.  All pointers can be converted to this type without loss of information, and it is specifically `void *` to which a `%p` specifier must correspond.

Comment: It's very hard for me not to try to figure out why data gets put in the wrong place when not using `void *`.

Comment: @SailorCire, I think you are missing the point.  Your original problem has nothing to do with failing to cast to `void *`, since you do not use any `%p` conversion specifiers.  Do not overlook that I give different conversion specifiers.  It is that you use conversion specifier `%x`, which is for type `unsigned int`, to try to format arguments of other types.  If I were to speculate about the actual undefined behavior, I would be especially suspicious of  argument `iov[0]`, the struct, which might be passed element-wise as multiple actual arguments.

Comment: @SailorCire, in any case, I don't see what's hard to understand about a requirement to match conversion specifiers to the types of the corresponding arguments.

Comment: So, the behavior is still considered undefined if I were to pass an int into a long? As in, if the parameter can be encapsulated into the argument, then it becomes undefined.

Comment: @SailorCire, yes, the behavior is undefined if the conversion specifier corresponding to an argument of type `int` indicates that a `long` should be expected (e.g. `%ld`).  It may turn out as you expected anyway, depending on C implementation and specific context, but that's one of the joys of undefined behavior: you cannot rely on it to work, but you *also* cannot rely on it to break (generally speaking).

Comment: Thanks for all the help and explanations!